# Why does my Android activity force close when I try to access info I put in the bundle?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bundle

I am writing an Android app. One of the activities is a ListActivity, so when the person selects an item in the list I would like the text value of that item to be stored in the Intent/Bundle so that the next activity knows that value. My code looks something like this:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), FavoriteEditFromDest.class);
            intent.putExtra("com.example.myapp.Name", ((TextView) view).getText());

            startActivity(intent);
        }
      });
    }
```

The onCreate method for the activity that is to be started looks like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.favorite_dest_edit);

            // nameB is a global string variable defined above.
        nameB = savedInstanceState.getString("com.example.myapp.Name");
    }
```

When I click an item from the list in the ListActivity, it begins to execute the onCreate code, but when it gets to the line that tries to retrieve the string value I get a force close dialog.

I don't have much experience passing information with a Bundle, so I would appreciate any and all help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
nameB = savedInstanceState.getString("com.example.myapp.Name");
```

should be replaced with

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
nameB = bundle.getString("com.example.myapp.Name");
```

try that out and see if it helps.

Comment: This looks promising, I will try it out and let you know how it goes. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine your stack trace and see the exception that triggered your "force close".

In this case, I suspect that you will find that what you put into the `Bundle` is not a `String`, since `getText()` does not return a `String`. However, that is just a guess -- your stack trace should tell you more.

Answer (score 0):

Among other problems

```
intent.putExtra("com.example.myapp.Name", ((TextView) view).getText());
```

Should be

```
intent.putExtra("com.example.myapp.Name", ((TextView) view).getText().toString());
```